# negation of "the need"

Tags: phrase-request, infinitive-vs-gerund

What is the negation of the below phrase?

> The need for tester programming

Is the below phrase true?

> Not the need for tester programming

What about below phrases?

> 1. not needing to tester programming
> 2. not need to tester programming
> 3. not needing tester programming

Comment: More context would help. Can you please provide the entire sentence? Negation is normally generally applied to a verb, but "the need" here is a noun.

Comment: @Otomatonium I want to list advantages of a tool. They are not complete sentences. They are phrases.

Comment: "The negation of"  a phrase doesn't make much sense to me. A phrase designates some (real, or abstract) object or objects: what would you mean by "the negation of" those objects? The absence of them? Something that is not identical with them? Something which is the antithesis of them, in some sense? It is not well defined what you mean.

Comment: It sounds like one advantage of the tool is "No need for tester programming."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The common negation of this expression would be:

> **No need for** (any) tester programming.

Examples:

> Although it is an important component of the design, there is **no need for** catastrophic failure testing.
>
> When designing the new site there should be **no need to** take our own developers off of critical tasks.  Everything can be done with outside consultants.

All of your examples are not natural English.

Side question:  I'm not sure "tester programming" is the correct phrase for what you are trying to say.  What exactly is the task?

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. Regarding "tester programming", I mean programming which is done by a tester (user).

Comment: @BA  It seems highly unusual to have the users do any *programming*.  I wonder instead if there's another term that fits better, like "writing tests" which is something testers commonly do.  "Programming" is generally done by core developers -- but it may be different in your industry.

Comment: Re-reading all answers and comments, I think that I've misunderstood what OP wanted. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the direct negation *no need for* in the first answer, I can suggest as alternatives:

> - ((You) can) **do without** tester programming
> - ((You) can) **omit** tester programming

or if there is a longer list of *successive* steps in a workflow and you can leave out this one step:

> - **skip** tester programming.